# Azure Function Set Environment variable java

Tags: java, environment-variables, azure-functions

I was trying Azure functions using java. And able to implement one simple function.

I know that any environment variable in local we can write those in **local.setting.json** however to environment variable in azure cloud we need to use in **Applications Setting** of azure cloud. Correct me If I am wrong.

**Now my scenario** :

I am looking for the thing to store environment variable from code only. Is there any way to store environment data in local.setting.json / applications setting from java code so that this environment value get persist for other azure function.

One thing That I thought of doing is using DB. But I have few key-value pairs for that I don't want to create DB ops.

**MY TOOLS** :

Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2245)
Function Runtime Version: (3.0.13139.0)

Please, any lead will be helpful. Ask in comment if not clear.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can get the environment variable which stored in application setting from functions in one function app **but we can't get it from other function app**. So if you want to get some key-value pairs from other function app, I suggest you to use Azure key vault to store the key-value pairs.

**1.** [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal#create-a-vault) a azure key vault and [add a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal#add-a-secret-to-key-vault) to to key vault (the secret is the environment variable which you stored in application settings).

[image]
In the screenshot above, I generate a secret with "testkey" as its key and with "testvalue" as its value.

**2.** Edit your java code as below:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.KeyVaultClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.SecretBundle;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AppServiceMSICredentials;

AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);
SecretBundle secret = keyVaultClient.getSecret("https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net/", "testkey");

return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + secret.value()).build();
```

The `https://xxxxx.vault.azure.net/` is the url of your key vault which you can find it in the "Overview" tab in your key vault on azure portal.

We also need to add the dependencies in the pom.xml in your function project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**3.** Deploy your function from local to azure and then enable MSI of your function on azure portal.

[image]

**4.** Grant your function app access to the key vault, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/managed-identity#grant-your-app-access-to-key-vault).

[image]

**5.** After that, run the function on azure portal, we can get the value of the key("testkey").

[image]

You can also get the key vault in other function by the steps above.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And also showing the example in this is helpful to understand how things with vault works. I have few doubt regarding what my requirement is. I need to store some key-value pair. Application setting is for this purpose to keep env variable there. Scenario is whatever key-value I receive from api call I need to store it as a env variable so that whenever any other function created it can take data directly using `System.getenv()`. Also I am little worried to create 4-5 Key value pair in Vault. Is it worth to create a vault service for that.

Comment: @Duega May I know if you want to get the environment from different functions in one function app ? Or from other function apps ?

Comment: @Duega I think I understand your requirement. You can request [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/WebApps/UpdateApplicationSettings#code-try-0) api in your function code to update the key-value in application settings. But you need to put not only one key-value which you want to add but also all of the key-values in the request body of the api because the request body will cover all of the values in app settings. By comparison, I think key vault is better.